# How to test if a triangle is behind, infront or inbetween another triangle from the perspective of a viewing point

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I want to test if triangle $A$ is in front or behind triangle $b$ from the perspective of a viewing point $P$.

My current procedure is using the standard form of a plane ($Ax+By+Cy+D=0$) but instead of using any point on the plane, I use the triangle points of the triangle a and the viewing point. Then I compare the signs of the results. If the signs of the results of the standard form using the triangle points are the same as the result of the standard form using the viewing point, then the triangle a is on the same side as the viewing point or automatically infront. If only some of the results of the standard form with the triangle points have the same sign as the result of the standard form using the viewing point, the triangle a intersects the triangle $b$. And the last possible outcome is that all the signs of the result of the standard form using the triangle points are the same but the sign of the result of the standard form using the viewing point meaning that triangle $a$ is behind triangle $b$.

But for some reason that doesn't work.

Here is exactly what I did:

- Calculate the normal of the plane of triangle $b$ (using this:https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal#Algorithm)
- Normalize
- Calculate Plane constant using a normalized normal vector and point 1 of the triangle as the origin.
- Do the standard for calculations with {$A,B,C$} = normalized normal vector {$X,Y,Z$}, {$x,y,z$} = Triangle A Point $1,2,3$/Viewing Point {$X,Y,Z$} - Triangle $B$ Point $1$ {$X,Y,Z$} and $D$ = Plane constant.
- Compare signs

I'm not sure if this extra Information helps, but I need this for creating a BSP tree.

Comment: @abiessu im not sure about what you achieve by taking the circumcenter of each triangle. But comparing the distances is a somewhat vaiable method. Its just not very accurate in some cases, thats why im asking

Comment: the idea was that the circumcenter distances would give a rough "which is closer" initial determination, then more detailed methods could further separate the case of "inbetween".

Comment: If it matters, your logical alternatives appear not to be exhaustive. For example, the planes of the triangles can intersect even if the triangles themselves do not; the triangles can be coplanar and disjoint, or can overlap in a complicated way.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know about that, but for now i want to start by being able to test if a point is infront, behind or inbtween a plane.

Comment: What does "inbetween a plane" mean? Do you mean "in a plane"?

Comment: It's not apparent (to me) that's what you're asking; might be worth updating your question? <> Anyway, if $O$ is a point of the plane, $n$ is a normal vector (not necessarily unit) to the plane, $P$ the point being tested, and $V$ the viewpoint, then $P$ and $V$ lie on the same side of the plane if and only if $$[(P-O)\cdot n][(V-O)\cdot n] > 0.$$If the expression on the left is negative, then $P$ and $V$ are on opposite sides; if $0$, then at least one of $P$ and $V$ lies in the plane.